# Eslint says all enums in Typescript app are "already declared in the upper scope"

Tags: node.js, typescript, eslint

Starting a new application, I installed eslint and configured it with the following configs, but every time I create an `enum` it says it had already been defined. Even nonsense strings. Other variable types (const, var, let) don't have this issue. I could disable the rule but I would like it applied for situations where it is actually true.

```
    {
  "root": true,
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint"],
  "parserOptions": {
    "project": ["./tsconfig.json"],
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "ecmaVersion": 6,
      "jsx": true
    }
  },
  "overrides": [],
  "extends": [
    "airbnb-typescript",
    "prettier",
    "prettier/@typescript-eslint",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "spaced-comment": 0,
    "import/prefer-default-export": 0,
    "@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define": 0,
    "@typescript-eslint/restrict-template-expressions": [
      1,
      { "allowBoolean": true }
    ],
    "react/jsx-props-no-spreading": "off",
    "react/state-in-constructor": 0,
    "react/require-default-props": 0,
    "react/destructuring-assignment": [
      1,
      "always",
      {
        "ignoreClassFields": true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: it's the base rule that is throwing the error, disable `no-shadow` and enable `@typescript-eslint/no-shadow`. see [this](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/2552#issuecomment-691694839) and it's subsequent links.

Comment: if `@typescript-eslint/no-shadow` gives you issues as well it's possible you are using an outdated version, see [this](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/2570) if that comes up.

Answer (score 241):

If you are a user of TSLint-to-ESLint this was [a bug that has since been fixed](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/tslint-to-eslint-config/issues/856) so rerunning the script with a newer version would also fix the issue, or just disable the `no-shadow` and enable `@typescript-eslint/no-shadow`

If you are using some public config that is misusing the rule then be sure to let them know, the number of people still running into this is somewhat staggering.

---

see [@typescript-eslint/no-shadow how to use](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-shadow/#how-to-use)
also [this section of FAQ](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/docs/getting-started/linting/FAQ.md#i-am-using-a-rule-from-eslint-core-and-it-doesnt-work-correctly-with-typescript-code)

### How to use

```js
module.exports = {
  "rules": {
    // Note: you must disable the base rule as it can report incorrect errors
    "no-shadow": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-shadow": "warn"
  }
};
```

Searching [typescript-eslint GitHub issues](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues?q=label%3A%22fix%3A+user+error%22+no-shadow) shows a number of people asking the same thing.

Comment: Could someone who runs into this please tell me what configuration you are using? if there is a commonly used public config that is misusing this rule I'd like to let them know.

Comment: im using the default config when u upgrade angular from tslint to eslint using the CLI

Comment: Confirming that this works with .eslintrc.json auto-generated by TSLint-to-ESLint tooling in Angular 11. You have to add the lines above skipping `{` and `}` to `overrides.rules[0]` (first item in the array). I would post the full config here, but it will be messed up in the comment. If this explanation is not clear enough I can create a GitHub gist.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen: This is the step which produces problematic configuration fixable by the lines you specified above:
https://github.com/angular-eslint/angular-eslint#step-2---run-the-convert-tslint-to-eslint-schematic-on-a-project

Comment: Can confirm, angular-eslint, the conversion from tslint to eslint, contains this issue.

Answer (score 45):

Tadhg McDonald-Jensen's answer is useful, but there is one thing that needs to be said. Writing the following configuration items directly to `.eslintrc` will report an error:

```
{
  // note you must disable the base rule as it can report incorrect errors
  "no-shadow": "off",
  "@typescript-eslint/no-shadow": ["error"]
}
```

Here's a correct example with the no-shadow rule:

```
{
  "rules": {
      "no-shadow": "off",
      "@typescript-eslint/no-shadow": ["error"]
  },
}
```

Comment: @Va5ili5: @Tadhg's answer was updated to include the `rules` key, so this answer no longer adds anything useful.

Answer (score 12):

I had similar issue with the following code in TypeScript:

```
export enum MyEnum {
  myValueOne = 'myValue',
  myValueTwo = 'myValueTwo', // <-- got "already declared in the upper scope” error
}

export class myValueTwo {
   constructor(){}
}
```

Unfortunately neither `rules` or `overrides` didn't solve issue

```
 {
   "rules": {
      "no-shadow": "off",
      "@typescript-eslint/no-shadow": ["error"]
   },
   "overrides": {
      "no-shadow": "off",
      "@typescript-eslint/no-shadow": ["error"]
   },
}
```

After spending few hours checking different Issues, questions and documentation about the problem I came across the official docs of `@typescript-eslint/no-shadow`. [Here is the link](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-shadow.md)

What I had to do is do add additional the `ignoreTypeValueShadow` options in eslint for `@typescript-eslint/no-shadow`.

My final setup for no-shadow looks like this:

```
{
  "overrides": {
    "no-shadow": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-shadow": ["error", , { "ignoreTypeValueShadow": true }]
  },
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like adding this to the base "rules" was not enough and I had to add it again under the overrides

```js
# eslintrc.js
{
  "rules": { // Did not work here as intended
    "@typescript-eslint/dot-notation": "error",
    "no-shadow": "off",
  },
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": [
          "*.ts"
      ],
      ...
      "rules": { // Here it worked
          "@typescript-eslint/dot-notation": "error",
          "no-shadow": "off",
      }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs for me when I declared a variable with the some name of the object. I forgot to put the variable name in lowarcase rather than uppercase which the name of the object. like TypeFile: TypeFile

**Solution:** To fix it just put the variable name in lowercase.

Example of code generating this Eslint error:

**This is my Enum: type-file-model.ts**

```
public enum TypeFichier {
XML, PDF, IMAGE, ZIP
}
```

**This is my object model app-file-model.ts**

```
import {TypeFile} from 'app/shared/model/enum/type-file.model';

export interface IAppFile {
  ...
  TypeFile?: TypeFile;
}

export class AppFile implements IAppFile{
  constructor(
    ...
    public TypeFile?: TypeFile
  ) {}
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I managed to stop the error from appearing using the following configuration:

```json
{
   "rules": {
      "no-shadow": "off",
      "@typescript-eslint/no-shadow": ["off"]
   }
}
```

Use "off" for both cases, as I notice a recurring pattern in all the examples I read, which use "off" in the first and "error" in the second. This makes me doubt that it is the correct way to do it, but I have not been able to avoid those errors in another way, not even using overwriting.

Comment: You're not avoiding the _errors_ this way, you're just ensuring that eslint doesn't report any to you. Those are two different rules, one (`no-shadow`) is a base js rule that doesn't work properly in TypeScript files - that's why you should turn it off _for Typescript files_. The other is from the `typescript-eslint` plugin, and it correctly identifies the error in Typescript files, so turn it on as an error or warning.