# declaring enum in typescript gives me error

Tags: typescript

In a typescript file at line 26 I have the following code:

```
export enum ItemType {
  Case = 'Case',
  Study = 'Study',
  Project = 'Project',
  Item = 'Item',
}
```

I am using Visual Studio Code as the IDE. The linting gives me an error `'ItemType' is already declared in the upper scope on line 26 column 13.eslint(no-shadow)`

The only place where `ItemType` is referenced is below in the same file in an interface definition:

```
export interface Item {
  // other fields here

  readonly type: ItemType;
}
```

Nowhere else in my project do I have a definition of anything called 'ItemType'. This is what makes understanding this error difficult. Why do I get this error, and how do I fix my code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Eslint says all enums in Typescript app are "already declared in the upper scope"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63961803/eslint-says-all-enums-in-typescript-app-are-already-declared-in-the-upper-scope)

Answer (score 5):

You need to turn off the regular *no-shadow* eslint rule and replace it with the typescript-eslint one.

So add this to your eslint configuration:

```
...
"no-shadow": "off",
"@typescript-eslint/no-shadow": ["error"],
...
```

Comment: This solution solves the problem, which I also had.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to replicate the issue with the `@typescript-eslint/parser` in a minimal env with your code. Not sure what linting-rules or styleguides you're using but adding the following rules to my `eslintrc.js` file did the trick

```
"rules": {
    "no-shadow": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-shadow": "off"
}
```