# Laravel IneriaJS with Breeze seems two have two vite instances in dev mode

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

Hey guys im facing a weird problem from yesterday actually couldn't try anything as I searched; it seems no one met anything like this! I tried to play around with files a bit but still the same! the problem is simple

I'm using Laravel Breeze & InertiaJS I've been using this for many projects but for this one, I don't know why when I'm running npm run dev to create my application in the dev environment it seems my app has two instances! for example, every inertia link loads the web state like always without refresh or reload first then does one refresh on the same URL! but when I do npm run build it's no more there! I really don't know what can cause this I'm sharing some files here if you need more let me know!

also I'm using Vuexy for this project as front-end template

package.json

```
{
    "name": "vuexy-vuejs-laravel-inertia-template",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build",
        "lint": "eslint . -c .eslintrc.js --fix --ext .ts,.js,.vue,.tsx,.jsx",
        "build:icons": "node resources/js/@iconify/build-icons.js",
        "postinstall": "npm run build:icons"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@antfu/eslint-config-vue": "0.38.5",
        "@casl/ability": "6.5.0",
        "@casl/vue": "2.2.1",
        "@floating-ui/dom": "1.2.7",
        "@fullcalendar/core": "6.1.6",
        "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "6.1.6",
        "@fullcalendar/interaction": "6.1.6",
        "@fullcalendar/list": "6.1.6",
        "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "6.1.6",
        "@fullcalendar/vue3": "6.1.6",
        "@iconify-json/fa": "1.1.4",
        "@iconify-json/tabler": "1.1.74",
        "@iconify/tools": "2.2.6",
        "@iconify/vue": "4.1.1",
        "@inertiajs/vue3": "^1.0.0",
        "@intlify/unplugin-vue-i18n": "0.10.0",
        "@tabler/icons": "2.17.0",
        "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.3",
        "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "4.2.1",
        "@vitejs/plugin-vue-jsx": "3.0.1",
        "@vueuse/core": "10.1.0",
        "@vueuse/math": "10.1.0",
        "apexcharts-clevision": "3.28.5",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.12",
        "axios": "1.4.0",
        "axios-mock-adapter": "1.21.4",
        "chart.js": "4.3.0",
        "eslint": "8.39.0",
        "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "15.0.0",
        "eslint-import-resolver-alias": "^1.1.2",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "2.27.5",
        "eslint-plugin-promise": "6.1.1",
        "eslint-plugin-regex": "1.10.0",
        "eslint-plugin-sonarjs": "0.19.0",
        "eslint-plugin-unicorn": "46.0.0",
        "eslint-plugin-vue": "9.11.0",
        "jwt-decode": "3.1.2",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.8.0",
        "pinia": "2.0.35",
        "postcss": "^8.4.18",
        "postcss-html": "1.5.0",
        "prismjs": "1.29.0",
        "roboto-fontface": "0.10.0",
        "sass": "1.62.1",
        "stylelint": "14.15.0",
        "stylelint-config-idiomatic-order": "9.0.0",
        "stylelint-config-standard-scss": "6.1.0",
        "stylelint-use-logical-spec": "4.1.0",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.2.1",
        "unplugin-auto-import": "0.15.3",
        "unplugin-vue-components": "0.24.1",
        "unplugin-vue-define-options": "1.3.4",
        "vite": "4.3.3",
        "vite-plugin-pages": "0.29.0",
        "vite-plugin-vue-layouts": "0.8.0",
        "vite-plugin-vuetify": "1.0.2",
        "vue": "3.2.47",
        "vue-chartjs": "5.2.0",
        "vue-flatpickr-component": "11.0.3",
        "vue-i18n": "9.2.2",
        "vue-prism-component": "2.0.0",
        "vue-router": "4.1.6",
        "vue-shepherd": "3.0.0",
        "vue3-apexcharts": "1.4.1",
        "vue3-perfect-scrollbar": "1.6.1",
        "vuetify": "3.2.1",
        "webfontloader": "1.6.28"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@casl/ability": "6.5.0",
        "@casl/vue": "2.2.1",
        "@floating-ui/dom": "1.2.7",
        "@tabler/icons": "2.17.0",
        "@vueuse/core": "10.1.0",
        "@vueuse/math": "10.1.0",
        "apexcharts-clevision": "3.28.5",
        "axios": "1.4.0",
        "axios-mock-adapter": "1.21.4",
        "chart.js": "4.3.0",
        "eslint-import-resolver-alias": "^1.1.2",
        "jwt-decode": "3.1.2",
        "pinia": "2.0.35",
        "prismjs": "1.29.0",
        "roboto-fontface": "0.10.0",
        "sass": "1.62.1",
        "unplugin-vue-define-options": "1.3.4",
        "vue": "3.2.47",
        "vue-chartjs": "5.2.0",
        "vue-flatpickr-component": "11.0.3",
        "vue-i18n": "9.2.2",
        "vue-prism-component": "2.0.0",
        "vue-router": "4.1.6",
        "vue-toastification": "^2.0.0-rc.5",
        "vue3-apexcharts": "1.4.1",
        "vue3-perfect-scrollbar": "1.6.1",
        "vuetify": "3.2.1",
        "webfontloader": "1.6.28" 
    },
    "packageManager": "yarn@1.22.18",
    "resolutions": {
        "postcss": "8"
    }
}
```

vite.config.json

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

import { fileURLToPath } from 'node:url'
import vueJsx from '@vitejs/plugin-vue-jsx'
import AutoImport from 'unplugin-auto-import/vite'
import Components from 'unplugin-vue-components/vite'
import Pages from 'vite-plugin-pages'
import Layouts from 'vite-plugin-vue-layouts'
import vuetify from 'vite-plugin-vuetify'
import VueI18nPlugin from '@intlify/unplugin-vue-i18n/vite'

// @ts-expect-error Known error: https://github.com/sxzz/unplugin-vue-macros/issues/257#issuecomment-1410752890
import DefineOptions from 'unplugin-vue-define-options/vite'


export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: 'resources/js/app.js',
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
        vueJsx(),
        vuetify({
            styles: {
              configFile: 'resources/styles/variables/_vuetify.scss',
            },
        }),
        Pages({
            dirs: ['./resources/js/pages'],
        }),
        Layouts({
            layoutsDirs: './resources/js/layouts/',
        }),
        Components({
            dirs: ['resources/js/@core/components', 'resources/js/views/demos', 'resources/js/components'],
            dts: true,
        }),
        AutoImport({
            eslintrc: {
                enabled: true,
                filepath: './.eslintrc-auto-import.json',
            },
            imports: ['vue', 'vue-router', '@vueuse/core', '@vueuse/math', 'vue-i18n', 'pinia'],
            vueTemplate: true,
        }),
        VueI18nPlugin({
            runtimeOnly: true,
            compositionOnly: true,
            include: [
              fileURLToPath(new URL('./resources/js/plugins/i18n/locales/**', import.meta.url)),
            ],
        }),
        DefineOptions(),
        
    ],
    define: { 'process.env': {} },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
          '@core-scss': fileURLToPath(new URL('./resources/styles/@core', import.meta.url)),
          '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./resources/js', import.meta.url)),
          '@themeConfig': fileURLToPath(new URL('./themeConfig.js', import.meta.url)),
          '@core': fileURLToPath(new URL('./resources/js/@core', import.meta.url)),
          '@layouts': fileURLToPath(new URL('./resources/js/@layouts', import.meta.url)),
          '@images': fileURLToPath(new URL('./resources/images/', import.meta.url)),
          '@styles': fileURLToPath(new URL('./resources/styles/', import.meta.url)),
          '@configured-variables': fileURLToPath(new URL('./resources/styles/variables/_template.scss', import.meta.url)),
          '@axios': fileURLToPath(new URL('./resources/js/plugins/axios', import.meta.url)),
          '@validators': fileURLToPath(new URL('./resources/js/@core/utils/validators', import.meta.url)),
          'apexcharts': fileURLToPath(new URL('node_modules/apexcharts-clevision', import.meta.url)),
        },
    },
    build: {
        chunkSizeWarningLimit: 5000,
    },
    
    // optimizeDeps: {
    //     exclude: ['vuetify'],
    //     entries: [
    //       './resources/js/**/*.vue',
    //     ],
    // },
    server: {
        watch: {
            usePolling: true
        }
    }
});
```

jsconfig.json

```
{
    "include": [
        "vite.config.*",
        "resources/js/**/*",
        "resources/js/**/*.vue",
        "themeConfig.js"
      ],
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "@/*": ["resources/js/*"],
            "@themeConfig": [
                "themeConfig.js"
            ],
            "@layouts/*": [
            "resources/js/@layouts/*"
            ],
            "@layouts": [
            "resources/js/@layouts"
            ],
            "@core/*": [
            "resources/js/@core/*"
            ],
            "@core": [
            "resources/js/@core"
            ],
            "@images/*": [
            "resources/images/*"
            ],
            "@styles/*": [
            "resources/styles/*"
            ],
            "@axios": [
            "resources/js/plugins/axios"
            ],
            "@validators": [
            "resources/js/@core/utils/validators"
            ],
            "@core-scss/*": [
            "resources/styles/@core"
            ]
        }
    },
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "public","resources/js/@iconify/*"]
}
```

.eslintrc.ts

```
module.exports = {
    env: {
      browser: true,
      es2021: true,
    },
    extends: [
      '.eslintrc-auto-import.json',
      'plugin:vue/vue3-recommended',
      'plugin:import/recommended',
      'plugin:promise/recommended',
      'plugin:sonarjs/recommended',
  
      // 'plugin:unicorn/recommended',
    ],
    parser: 'vue-eslint-parser',
    parserOptions: {
      ecmaVersion: 13,
      sourceType: 'module',
    },
    plugins: [
      'vue',
      'regex',
    ],
    ignorePatterns: ['resources/js/@iconify/*.js', 'node_modules', 'dist'],
    rules: {
      'no-console': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'warn' : 'off',
      'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'warn' : 'off',
  
      // indentation (Already present in TypeScript)
      'comma-spacing': ['error', { before: false, after: true }],
      'key-spacing': ['error', { afterColon: true }],
  
      'vue/first-attribute-linebreak': ['error', {
        singleline: 'beside',
        multiline: 'below',
      }],
  
  
      // indentation (Already present in TypeScript)
      //'indent': ['error', 'never'],
  
      // Enforce trailing comma (Already present in TypeScript)
      'comma-dangle': ['error', 'always-multiline'],
  
      // Enforce consistent spacing inside braces of object (Already present in TypeScript)
      'object-curly-spacing': ['error', 'always'],
  
      // Disable max-len
      'max-len': 'off',
  
      // we don't want it
      'semi': ['error', 'never'],
  
      // add parens ony when required in arrow function
      'arrow-parens': ['error', 'as-needed'],
  
      // add new line above comment
      'newline-before-return': 'error',
  
      // add new line above comment
      'lines-around-comment': [
        'error',
        {
          beforeBlockComment: true,
          beforeLineComment: true,
          allowBlockStart: true,
          allowClassStart: true,
          allowObjectStart: true,
          allowArrayStart: true,
        },
      ],
  
      // Ignore _ as unused variable
  
      'array-element-newline': ['error', 'consistent'],
      'array-bracket-newline': ['error', 'consistent'],
  
      'vue/multi-word-component-names': 'off',
  
      'padding-line-between-statements': [
        'error',
        { blankLine: 'always', prev: 'expression', next: 'const' },
        { blankLine: 'always', prev: 'const', next: 'expression' },
        { blankLine: 'always', prev: 'multiline-const', next: '*' },
        { blankLine: 'always', prev: '*', next: 'multiline-const' },
      ],
  
      // Plugin: eslint-plugin-import
      'import/prefer-default-export': 'off',
      'import/newline-after-import': ['error', { count: 1 }],
      'no-restricted-imports': ['error', 'vuetify/components'],
  
      // For omitting extension for ts files
      'import/extensions': [
        'error',
        'ignorePackages',
        {
          js: 'never',
          jsx: 'never',
          ts: 'never',
          tsx: 'never',
        },
      ],
  
      // ignore virtual files
      'import/no-unresolved': [2, {
        ignore: [
          '~pages$',
          'virtual:generated-layouts',
  
          // Ignore vite's ?raw imports
          '.*\?raw',
        ],
      }],
  
      // Thanks: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63961972/10796681
      'no-shadow': 'off',
  
  
      // Plugin: eslint-plugin-promise
      'promise/always-return': 'off',
      'promise/catch-or-return': 'off',
  
      // ESLint plugin vue
      'vue/block-tag-newline': 'error',
      'vue/component-api-style': 'error',
      'vue/component-name-in-template-casing': ['error', 'PascalCase', { registeredComponentsOnly: false }],
      'vue/custom-event-name-casing': ['error', 'camelCase', {
        ignores: [
          '/^(click):[a-z]+((\d)|([A-Z0-9][a-z0-9]+))*([A-Z])?/',
        ],
      }],
      'vue/define-macros-order': 'error',
      'vue/html-comment-content-newline': 'error',
      'vue/html-comment-content-spacing': 'error',
      'vue/html-comment-indent': 'error',
      'vue/match-component-file-name': 'error',
      'vue/no-child-content': 'error',
      'vue/require-default-prop': 'off',
  
      // NOTE this rule only supported in SFC,  Users of the unplugin-vue-define-options should disable that rule: https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue/issues/1886
      // 'vue/no-duplicate-attr-inheritance': 'error',
      'vue/no-empty-component-block': 'error',
      'vue/no-multiple-objects-in-class': 'error',
      'vue/no-reserved-component-names': 'error',
      'vue/no-template-target-blank': 'error',
      'vue/no-useless-mustaches': 'error',
      'vue/no-useless-v-bind': 'error',
      'vue/padding-line-between-blocks': 'error',
      'vue/prefer-separate-static-class': 'error',
      'vue/prefer-true-attribute-shorthand': 'error',
      'vue/v-on-function-call': 'error',
      'vue/no-restricted-class': ['error', '/^(p|m)(l|r)-/'],
      'vue/valid-v-slot': ['error', {
        allowModifiers: true,
      }],
  
      // -- Extension Rules
      'vue/no-irregular-whitespace': 'error',
      'vue/template-curly-spacing': 'error',
  
      // -- Sonarlint
      'sonarjs/no-duplicate-string': 'off',
      'sonarjs/no-nested-template-literals': 'off',
  
      // -- Unicorn
      // 'unicorn/filename-case': 'off',
      // 'unicorn/prevent-abbreviations': ['error', {
      //   replacements: {
      //     props: false,
      //   },
      // }],
  
      // https://github.com/gmullerb/eslint-plugin-regex
      /*
      'regex/invalid': [
        'error',
        [
          {
            regex: '@/assets/images',
            replacement: '@images',
            message: 'Use \'@images\' path alias for image imports',
          },
          {
            regex: '@/styles',
            replacement: '@styles',
            message: 'Use \'@styles\' path alias for importing styles from \'resources/js/styles\'',
          },
  
          // {
          //   id: 'Disallow icon of icon library',
          //   regex: 'tabler-\\w',
          //   message: 'Only \'mdi\' icons are allowed',
          // },
  
          {
            regex: '@core/\\w',
            message: 'You can\'t use @core when you are in @layouts module',
            files: {
              inspect: '@layouts/.*',
            },
          },
          {
            regex: 'useLayouts\\(',
            message: '`useLayouts` composable is only allowed in @layouts & @core directory. Please use `useThemeConfig` composable instead.',
            files: {
              inspect: '^(?!.*(@core|@layouts)).*',
            },
          },
          {
            regex: 'import axios from \'axios\'',
            replacement: 'import axios from \'@axios\'',
            message: 'Use axios instances created in \'resources/js/plugin/axios.js\' instead of unconfigured axios',
            files: {
              ignore: '^.*plugins/axios.js.*',
            },
          },
        ],
  
        // Ignore files
        '\.eslintrc\.js',
      ],
      */
    },
    settings: {
      'import/resolver': {
        node: {
          extensions: ['.js', '.js', '.jsx', '.jsx', '.mjs', '.png', '.jpg'],
        }, alias: { 'extensions': ['.ts', '.js', '.tsx', '.jsx', '.mjs'], 'map': [["@", "./resources/js"], ["@themeConfig", "./themeConfig.js"], ["@core", "./resources/js/@core"], ["@layouts", "./resources/js/@layouts"], ["@images", "./resources/images/"], ["@styles", "./resources/styles/"], ["@configured-variables", "./resources/styles/variables/_template.scss"], ["@axios", "./resources/js/plugins/axios"], ["@validators", "./resources/js/@core/utils/validators"], ["apexcharts", "node_modules/apexcharts-clevision"]] },
      },
    },
  }
```

and finally my app.js

```
import './bootstrap'
import '../css/app.css'

import { createApp, h } from 'vue'
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/vue3'
import { resolvePageComponent } from 'laravel-vite-plugin/inertia-helpers'
import { ZiggyVue } from '../../vendor/tightenco/ziggy/dist/vue.m'


import '@/@iconify/icons-bundle'
import AppLayout from '@/App.vue'
import layoutsPlugin from '@/plugins/layouts'
import vuetify from '@/plugins/vuetify'
import { loadFonts } from '@/plugins/webfontloader'
import router from '@/router'
import '@core-scss/template/index.scss'
import '@styles/styles.scss'
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'
import i18n from '@/plugins/i18n'
import Toast from "vue-toastification"
import "vue-toastification/dist/index.css"

loadFonts()

const appName = import.meta.env.VITE_APP_NAME || 'Laravel'
import { useThemeConfig } from '@core/composable/useThemeConfig'

const {
    isAppRtl,
  } = useThemeConfig()

createInertiaApp({
    title: title => `${title} - ${appName}`,
    
    //resolve: (name) => resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/${name}.vue`, import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue')),
    resolve: name => {
        const pages = import.meta.glob('./pages/**/*.vue', { eager: true })
        let page = pages[`./pages/${name}.vue`]
        page.default.layout = page.default.layout || AppLayout  

        return page
    },
    setup({ el, App, props, plugin }) {
        const toastOptions = {
            // You can set your default options here
            rtl: isAppRtl.value,
        }

        return createApp({ render: () => h(App, props) })
            .use(plugin)
            .use(vuetify)
            .use(Toast, toastOptions)
            .use(createPinia())
            .use(layoutsPlugin)//check
            .use(ZiggyVue, Ziggy)
            .use(i18n)
            .mount(el)
    },
    progress: {
        color: '#4B5563',
    },
});
```